# How to mirror linux/rpi-linux kernel to private repo

Tags: linux, git

I am attempting to mirror the linux/rpi-linux kernel and store it on my private repo - I plan on doing a number of changes for a personal distribution. Id like the updates from the kernel to update in my private repo whenever they are avaliable.  I have tried the following method but run into a number of issues:

```
$ git clone --mirror git@example.com/upstream-repository.git
$ cd upstream-repository.git
$ git push --mirror git@example.com/new-location.git
```

Obviously with the repo URLS changed to that of either the linux kernel or others.

Every time I try git push, I get:

> Connection to github.com closed by remote host.fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I have tested this method for smaller repos, and it works well. But on larger repos it fails completely.  URL is not http based, but ssh.

Has anyone dealt with or succeeded? I know it is possible as I have seen it on some private repos. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: It seems likely that your `git push` command takes long enough that the ssh connection times out before your Git starts sending data to GitHub. You might look to see if there's already an existing GitHub mirror you could fork, which would sidestep the problem and be friendlier to GitHub itself.